# Retrieving data from Firebase Realtime Database working intermittently now

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a project that has a database connected which stores approximately only 3MB of text.

I had everything working perfectly up until recently but now it works intermittently.

I manually load new data to the database each morning and then in the applicationWillTerminate() func in the AppDelegate it changes one child of one branch from the word "YES" to "NO" in the afternoon.

When I load the app and try to retrieve data from the database it ALWAYS works perfectly on the first attempt and loads the required data within 1-2 seconds which is fine.

If I then try to retrieve more data from the database or subsequently retrieve the same data it takes several minutes to load on the first attempt that day.
Once it has finally retrieved the data on the second occasion, it then works perfectly on every attempt thereafter until the following day regardless of how many times I reopen the app, occasionally it will work perfectly for a few days, even after more daily uploads to the database.

//Save to database

```
func saveFirstThingToDatabase()
{
    firstThingEntered = "YES"
    
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "*dailyFirstThing")
    
    let savingThings = ["firstThingEntered": "\(firstThingEntered)",
        "someThing1": "\(savingThing1)",
        "someThing2": "\(savingThing2)",
        "someThing3": "\(savingThing3)",
        "someThing4": "\(savingThing4)",
        "someThing5": "\(savingThing5)"]
    
    ref.child("dailyThing").updateChildValues(savingThings,
                                             withCompletionBlock:
        {
            (error, ref) in
            if let error = error
            {
                print("Failed to update database values with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            else
            {
                print("DAILY THING 1 SAVED SUCCESSFULLY!")
            }
    })
}


func saveAnotherThingToDatabase()
{
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "otherThingWithDates")
    let withDates = "withDates"
    let addingThings = ref.child(withDates)

    let addingData = data
    
    let addData: [String: [String]] = ["addOtherThingWithDates": addingData]

    addingThings.setValue(addData)
    {
        (error:Error?, ref:DatabaseReference) in
        if let error = error
        {
            print("Data could not be saved: \(error).")
        }
        else
        {
            print("DAILY THINGS WITH DATES SAVED SUCCESSFULLY!")
        }
    }
}
```

//Load from database

```
func loadFirstThingFromDatabase()
{
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "*dailyFirstThing")
    
    ref.child("dailyThing").child("dailyThing1").observe(.value)
    {
        (snapshot)
        in
        guard let dailyThing1 = snapshot.value
            else
        {
            return
        }
          self.someLabel.text = "\(dailyThing1)"
    }
} 



func loadAnotherThingFromDatabase()
{
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "otherThingWithDates/withDates/addOtherThingWithDates")
    ref.observe(.value, with:
       {
            (snapshot) in
            let new = (snapshot.value)
            self.data = new as! [String]
       })
}
```

Just to reiterate, this has all been working perfectly up until recently.

The structure of any path is no more than three branches, the majority of data is held in the third branch though.

I had a suspicion that it was my internet connection but both connections have download speeds of 55mbps and 70mbps.

I thought it may have had something to do with uploading the data and then having to wait for it to download properly but occasionally downloading to the device works instantly after uploading to the database.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!